# How is a rule in CLIPS mathematically defined?

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, clips, expert-system

I am trying to understand the mathematical concepts behind CLIPS programming language and I am not sure how is a rule in CLIPS mathematically defined ? Is it a set ?
Does the order of the set matters? Is there any place where I can read more about theoretical concepts of CLIPS language ?

Answer (score 0):

CLIPS uses the rete algorithm. Here's some links for more information:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm
http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/1995/CMU-CS-95-113.pdf
http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/scan/CMU-CS-79-forgy.pdf
https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/Misc/CLIPS_Implementation_of_Rete.pdf/download